# Is it possible to get out of case in oracle sql if first condition is met?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

For eg is there any keyword or method to perform below stuff:

```
SELECT  CASE
          WHEN ENAME like 'Arnold%' THEN DESIGNATION
          /* something_which_can_exit_without_going_to_next_case */
          ELSE ENAME
        END AS "RESULT"
FROM    EMP;
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and you don't need to do anything special, because that is how `case` works! It does short-circuit evaluation: it evaluates each `when` condition, and as soon as the first TRUE one is found, no further evaluation (of the other `when` conditions) is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you understand how a `CASE` works?  It evaluates the conditions until the first is met.  Consider this query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ENAME like 'Arnold%' THEN DESIGNATION
             ELSE ENAME
        END) AS RESULT
FROM EMP;
```

It returns `DESIGNATION` when the condition is met and `ENAME` when it is not.  If you want `NULL` when things don't match, then leave out the `ELSE` clause:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ENAME like 'Arnold%' THEN DESIGNATION
        END) AS RESULT
FROM EMP;
```

If you only want `ENAME`s that match the condition in the result set, then use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT DESIGNATION AS RESULT
FROM EMP
WHERE ENAME like 'Arnold%';
```

Comment: I think my question is not detailed enough, also the example query isnt fitting.
Suppose we have a table ABC:
COL
a
b

Comment: @AshPanwar . . . Ask another question with sample data, desired results, and a better explanation.

Comment: Sure I'll frame question in better way. I think I didnt do it correctly this time. Thanks Gordon for the answer up there though.

Comment: @AshPanwar . . . You should do it as *another* question.  Changing a question after it has answers can draw downvotes to the answers.